# Golang Colly Scraping - Website Captcha Catches My Scrape

Tags: go, web-scraping, reverse-proxy, go-colly

I did make Scraping for Amazon Product Titles but Amazon captcha catches my scraper. I tried 10 times- go run main.go(8 times catches me - 2 times I **scraped** the product title)

I researched this but I did not find any solution for golang(there is just python) is there any solution for me?

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"0

    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {

    // Create a Collector specifically for Shopify
    c := colly.NewCollector(
        colly.AllowedDomains("www.amazon.com", "amazon.com"),
    )
    c.OnHTML("div", func(h *colly.HTMLElement) {
        capctha := h.Text
        title := h.ChildText("span#productTitle")
        fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(title))
        fmt.Println(strings.TrimSpace(capctha))
    })

    // Start the collector
    c.Visit("https://www.amazon.com/Bluetooth-Over-Ear-Headphones-Foldable-Prolonged/dp/B07K5214NZ")
}
```

> Output:
>
> Enter the characters you see below Sorry, we just need to make sure
> you're not a robot. For best results, please make sure your browser is
> accepting cookies.

Comment: Do you want to bypass captcha? Captcha exists to block bots, so your code.

Comment: I always use goquery and 
I never got any captcha https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery

Comment: Thank you @Milad , I did not know goQuery, I will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind a different package, I wrote a package to search HTML
(essentially thin wrapper around `github.com/tdewolff/parse`):

```
package main

import (
   "github.com/89z/parse/html"
   "net/http"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   req, err := http.NewRequest(
      "GET", "https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07K5214NZ", nil,
   )
   req.Header = http.Header{
      "User-Agent": {"Mozilla"},
   }
   res, err := new(http.Transport).RoundTrip(req)
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   defer res.Body.Close()
   lex := html.NewLexer(res.Body)
   lex.NextAttr("id", "productTitle")
   os.Stdout.Write(lex.Bytes())
}
```

Result:

```
Bluetooth Headphones Over-Ear, Zihnic Foldable Wireless and Wired Stereo
Headset Micro SD/TF, FM for Cell Phone,PC,Soft Earmuffs &Light Weight for
Prolonged Waring(Rose Gold)
```

https://github.com/89z/parse